# Extract 2 times from a cell and put into two different columns?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet like so:

Column B:

```
The Auditor arrived at 9am and left at 2pm
The Auditor arrived 09:00, left 16:00
```

I am wanting to extract the start time that the auditor arrived and place this into column C like so:

Column C

```
9
9
```

And then extract the end time and put this into column D.

Column D

```
2
4
```

Then in column E i want to count the number of hours the auditor was on site:

Column E

```
5
7
```

At the moment I am using this formula to identify the location of the first number in my cell:

This is the formula in column C I am using to try and retrieve the number:

```
=MID(B18,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B18&"0123456789")),1)
```

My problem is this only works if the start time is one digit not two or more, so either 9am not 09:00.

Please can someone show me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution.  Even though you did not ask for VBA, a UDF (user defined function) for this purpose is relatively simple to write, and to alter in the future.  I used a *regular expression* to recognize the times.

The acceptable time formats include those showing in your example, with or without a space between the digit and the am/pm, along with a time like 2:00 PM or similar.  Easy to add in other time formats if necessary.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=ExtrTm(B1)
=ExtrTm(B1,1)
=ExtrTm(B1,2)
```

in some cell.

The second argument (if omitted it defaults to one), determines whether to extract the 1st or 2nd (or nth if there are more) times from the string.

**EDIT:**  Code edited to provide Regex that allows for optional use of `dot` (`.`) as a time separator.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtrTm(S As String, Optional tmIndex As Long = 1) As Date
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    'Const sPat As String = "\d+(?::\d+)?\s*(?:am|pm)?"

    'To allow for optional use of dot as a time separator, use
    Const sPat As String = "\d+(?:[:.]\d+)?\s*(?:am|pm)?"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .ignorecase = True
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ExtrTm = CDate(MC(tmIndex - 1))
    End If
End With

End Function
```

---

The result is as an Excel time which is a fraction of a day.  If you format the result as time, you will see your results in a human readable fashion.  If you need it in terms of decimal hours, (so as to multiply by an hourly rate, for example), merely multiply the returned value by 24.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. This almost seems to be working. However in one cell I have,  8.30am/4.10pm and the code gives me 00:00:00. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Yes thank you for your comment. I have removed my last comment as i did not properly read your comment about formating the cell as time.,

Comment: Probably we just need to change the regex pattern to optionally accept `dot` as a separator.  This may cause problems if you have decimal numbers embedded in the string not having to do with time.  I will edit the answer.

Comment: DId you get a chance to tweak the answer? Happy to accept when works in full. The other issue i'm having is a cell has Audit at 8.00 h until 18.00 h

Comment: ah but doesn't work for this cell  'On site :8:20    Off site 16:55'

Comment: @user7415328 What do you mean by `doesn't work`? I copy/pasted that line and it returns: `8:20:00 AM 4:55:00 PM 8:35` which is what I would expect.

Comment: ah seems to be working now. My fault. had manual calc on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this scary formula? Place it on `C18` cell...

`=24*IF(OR(IFERROR(FIND("am";MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5);1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("pm";MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5);1);0)>0)=TRUE;TIMEVALUE(MID(MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5);1;MIN(FIND({"am";"pm"};MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5)&"ampm";1)-1))&" "&MID(MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5);MIN(FIND({"am";"pm"};MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5)&"ampm";1));2));TIMEVALUE(MID(B18;MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};B18&"0123456789"));5)))`